# ValueError: shapes (1,1000) and (1,1000) not aligned: 1000 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0) When numpy.dot() with two matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to multiply two matrices using numpy.dot() and they are the same dimensions. But when i try to do it numpy gives me the error in the title saying that they are not aligned which doesnt make sense to me because they are the same dimensions. Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the code and sample matrices

Comment: Matrix multiplication between two 1x1000 matrices doesn't make sense. Having the same dimensions isn't the criterion for a matrix multiplication to be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape is the issue

```
a = np.arange(3).reshape(1,3)
b = np.arange(3,6).reshape(1,3)

np.dot(a, b)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-88-c9cc415545b4>", line 1, in <module>
    np.dot(a, b)

ValueError: shapes (1,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)


c = b.reshape(3,1)

np.dot(a,c)
array([[14]])
```